# How to alphabetize an combobox in java? (Using Netbeans IDE 7.3)

Tags: java, netbeans, combobox, sorting

I do have an combobox with different values like "FT001" and "FT002 and "FT003".
The problem is if i add FT002 before FT001 then the "FT002" is always first.

now i am looking for a method that is going to sort it on alphabeth.

i am using the following code to fill the combobox with:

```
public DefaultComboBoxModel getPraktijkenLijst(){
   DefaultComboBoxModel listModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

    listModel.addElement("Selecteer een praktijk");

    int aantal = praktijkVerzameling.getAantalPraktijken();
    int i = 0;
    while(i < aantal){   
        listModel.addElement(praktijkVerzameling.getPraktijk(i).getPraktijkNaam());
        i++;
    }
    return listModel;     
}
```

the "praktijkVerzameling" is an ArrayList filled with objects.

if you guys need anymore information to help me, please ask :)

PS:  I am dutch, so if there is anyone dutch here, i will understand dutch better then english, thanks.

Comment: Sort the list before entering the loop containing `addElement()`?   If you're pulling the project list from a database, sorting it on the select is a good way.

Answer (score 0):

`DefaultComboBoxModel.addElement(Object)`: Adds an item at the end of the model. So The array list you are using, can be sorted before adding to the `model` using `model.addElement(Object)` function. You can use a comparator to sort the `praktijkVerzameling` `ArrayList`. For example, assumin `praktijkVerzameling` is an array list of Class Type `Praktijk`:

```
       DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
       Collections.sort(praktijkVerzameling, new Comparator<Praktijk>(){

            @Override
            public int compare(Praktijk o1, Praktijk o2) {
               return o1.getPraktijkNaam().compareTo(o2.getPraktijkNaam()) ;
            }
        });

       for(Praktijk p : praktijkVerzameling)
           model.addElement(p.getPraktijkNaam());

       return model;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line :

```
DefaultComboBoxModel listModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
```

with :

```
  DefaultComboBoxModel  listModel = new SortedComboBoxModel();
```

Add this class :

```
 class SortedComboBoxModel extends DefaultComboBoxModel
 {
      public SortedComboBoxModel()
      {
           super();
      }



      public void addElement(Object element)
      {
           int index = 0;
           int size = getSize();

           //  Determine where to insert element to keep list in sorted order

           for (index = 0; index < size; index++)
           {
                Comparable c = (Comparable)getElementAt( index );

                if (c.compareTo(element) > 0)
                     break;
           }

           super.insertElementAt(element, index);
      }

      public void insertElementAt(Object element, int index)
      {
           addElement( element );
      }
 }
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: This is strictly an order of `(n^2)` solution. I hope you understand how worse the performance can be! :) :)